# TS: How to check if unknown object has a property?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have to write a function to recognize if unknown value has specific property. Unfortunately typescript still don't know what kind of value I have.

Here is my code:

```
export function isMySpecificError(error: unknown) {
  if (error && typeof error === 'object' && 'code' in error && error.hasOwnProperty('code')) {

    //TS2339: Property 'code' does not exist on type 'object'.
    return typeof error.code === 'string';
  }
}
```

I know my if statement could be written differently but I can't understand why typescript still doesn't know if property 'code' exist in 'error' after double check `'code' in error && error.hasOwnProperty('code')`

Here is my current solution which works, but I had to declare new type for 'error' instead of check it:

```
export function isMySpecificError(error: unknown): error is MySpecificError {
  if (error && typeof error === 'object' && error.hasOwnProperty('code')) {
    const errorWithCodeProperty = error as { code: unknown };
    return typeof errorWithCodeProperty.code === 'string' && errorWithCodeProperty.code.startsWith('someErrorCodeValue');
  }
  return false;
}
```

Could it be simplified? Is it possible to check differently if unknown object has a specific property?

Answer (score 2):

Your current solution is a good workaround for the moment and you might want to keep it as it is. But looking at the future, TypeScript 4.9 will introduce [improvements to control flow analysis regarding the `in` operator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-rc/#in-narrowing).

Up to version 4.9, using the `in` operator on values of type `object` had no impact on the narrowing of the type. But in future versions, types will be intersected with `Record<"propName", unknown>` which makes the error disappear.

```
// version 4.9

function isMySpecificError(error: unknown) {
  if (error && typeof error === 'object' && 'code' in error && error.hasOwnProperty('code')) {

    error
//  ^? error: object & Record<"code", unknown>

    return typeof error.code === 'string';
  }
  return false;
}
```

[Playground 4.9](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=5.0.0-dev.20221125#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAjgZwLIE8DKAHAUyjhDigFEAnShSgCgOtoC5lIBrCBAdwgEpkAb2DJUIZAyaVkAMhnIYWQgnGMa0gLxbkAcgQAjAFZEYO2fJ1QEAEwJm4KNbXPInlAHQALAIZoA8rwACjSElIp0ljZ2fALCIqKuUsAA9MmiAHoA-InqrAbGsLLIAEpEtNYAPABEVrZVADRsEJw8EAB8wPGilAQwYJQoisqqUu61BMhaGrpoMJQOAOY6ANzxAL6d3b39KCDeADZoBKtrQA)

Answer (score 0):

```
interface ErrorWithCode<T extends number = number> extends Error {
  code: T
}

function isErrorWithCode<T extends number>(
  err: ErrorWithCode<T> | unknown
): err is ErrorWithCode<T> {
  return err instanceof Error && 'code' in err;
}

let e = Object.assign(new Error(), {code: 444 as const})

if (isErrorWithCode(e)) {
  e.code // 444
  // ^?
}

let e1 = new Error()
if (isErrorWithCode(e1)) {
  e1.code // number
  // ^?
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=2&pln=3&pc=1#code/FDCWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACAorWB7WB1USACwGEcATaAHgBU1oAPGcCgZzXAFcBbAIzhoAvJ14DYAPgbNorDllyw0Ab2Bo0yStABcaWsAC%20IeF3DJIoHODSg2CvIRLkqdaS3aj%20cCQAo1DbF17AiIyLTopAB80UwBrcBwAd3BgAEpdOCVbTGwHUOcaWilVdVhoSC5Ya0ybcDZIRDNoHHgcxTQAMg60AHJNKh7agNgAbkMQABtyhmE0AHk%20ACtocwA6RDY2UABzcB9waES2vB9UgBoVfp00ABY7tA2NK3qDVJBQVp9bYMcwqh9oKlUip-NBVlc0AB6SG3O7%20aFoAB6AH5xsAppAGABGWYHI7BU5gT7fXIhJxaAFYoEg9TQLHgrRQmHcLyweEwlGGIA)